# StreamCorruptedException при десериализации

Tags: java, android, потоки-данных, сериализация

При попытке десериализовать данные вылетает такого рода ошибка. Вылетает она в следующей строке :

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
```

А вот код всего методa (bookPrefs - объкт SharedPreferences, books - ArrayList с объектами кастомного, сериализуемого класса.):

```
void loadBooks(){
    StringBuilder bytes = new StringBuilder();

    // FIXME: 06.03.2017 Здесь тоже убрать создание объекта.
    //Файл для десериализации
    File f = new File(PATH_TO_DESERIALIZABLE_DATA);

    bookPrefs = getActivity().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    bytes.append(bookPrefs.getString(PREFS, ""));

    //Запись байтов в файл
    try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(PATH_TO_DESERIALIZABLE_DATA))) {

        writer.write(bytes.toString());
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "FileNotFound!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "IOException with load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Десериализация
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_DESERIALIZABLE_DATA);
        // FIXME: 06.03.2017 ДЕСЕРИАЛИЗАЦИЯ
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        books = (ArrayList<Book>) ois.readObject();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Class nf", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "IOException with deser", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать для записи ObjectOutputStream

Answer (score 1):

Из документации:

> An ObjectInputStream deserializes primitive data and objects previously written using an ObjectOutputStream.

Вы же записываете с помощью `OutputStreamWriter`, это и приводит к появлению исключения, поскольку заголовок читаемых данных не соответствует ожидаемому.

Comment: Т.е. мне нужно использовать ObjectOuputStream? Но тогда он ругается, что я ему не тот стрим передаю

Comment: Измените мой код должным образом ибо я не понимаю как его исправить. что бы ошибка ушла